# R: regression analysis between two numeric variables stratified by groups

Tags: regression

This was initially posted on Stackoverflow but based on a suggestion, I am posting it here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62028326/r-regression-analysis-between-two-numeric-variables-stratified-by-groups

I have the following data frame of 48 samples with the following columns: `sample` (sample identifier), `gene` (log2 gene expression of a randomly selected gene), `label` (exercised vs non-exercised mice), `strain` (strain of the mice), `weight` (weight of mice), `running.time` (how much time spent on treadmill) and `VO2max` (maximum O2 consumption).

```
> head(test)

  sample     label  strain weight   VO2max running.time     gene
1    A81 exercised ANT1 ME   28.8 6192.907     21.00000 18.26548
2    A13 exercised ANT1 ME   26.8 6598.627     22.25000 17.55368
3    A43 exercised ANT1 ME   26.4 6368.918     20.33333 17.45001
4    A76 exercised ANT1 ME   23.0 6947.636     18.41667 17.87199
5    A17 exercised ANT1 ME   25.8 6526.043     21.58333 17.64396
6    A30 exercised ANT1 ME   29.2 6562.106     20.58333 17.81958

> dput(test)

structure(list(sample = c("A81", "A13", "A43", "A76", "A17", 
"A30", "A58", "A75", "A82", "A88", "A4", "A18", "I50", "I94", 
"I75", "I59", "I63", "I84", "I13", "I95", "I18", "I100", "I62", 
"I85", "B69", "B80", "B11", "B9", "B98", "B4", "B70", "B19", 
"B85", "B3", "B10", "B47", "E56", "E76", "E12", "E78", "E1", 
"E50", "E42", "E64", "E98", "E100", "E7", "E53"), label = c("exercised", 
"exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", 
"exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", 
"exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", 
"exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", "exercised", 
"exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", "exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", "non_exercised", 
"non_exercised", "non_exercised"), strain = c("ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", 
"ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", 
"ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "ANT1 ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", 
"IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", 
"IAI ME", "IAI ME", "IAI ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", 
"B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", "B6 ME", 
"B6 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", 
"EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", "EC77 ME", 
"EC77 ME"), weight = c(28.8, 26.8, 26.4, 23, 25.8, 29.2, 27.6, 
25, 28.6, 29.4, 29, 29.2, 31.6, 29.9, 34, 32.5, 31.7, 31, 28.8, 
29.8, 27.9, 32.8, 32.1, 29, 32.2, 28.4, 30, 26.3, 27.8, 30.8, 
32.1, 28, 30, 35.3, 29.9, 29.6, 30, 31, 24, 25.8, 27.4, 30, 31, 
30.4, 28, 27.7, 26.25, 29.1), VO2max = c(6192.907, 6598.627, 
6368.918, 6947.636, 6526.043, 6562.106, 6626.237, 6464.229, 6692.121, 
6990.765, 6586.469, 6773.607, 7755.965, 8504.163, 8081.548, 7500.55, 
7693.678, 7909.825, 7588.132, 6710.412, 6846.685, 7498.796, 7196.46, 
7856.87, 7605.042, 8616.026, 7942.862, 8306.043, 7949.328, 8376.683, 
8480.413, 7422.928, 8006.701, 7987.724, 8091.422, 7622.233, 7396.47, 
7538.512, 7144.345, 7032.685, 6621.896, 7800.92, 6900.873, 7078.454, 
6846.685, 6165.303, 7327.488, 6787.016), running.time = c(21, 
22.25, 20.3333333333333, 18.4166666666667, 21.5833333333333, 
20.5833333333333, 18.75, 17.5833333333333, 20.9166666666667, 
20.9166666666667, 19.3333333333333, 19.6666666666667, 36.75, 
35.5, 33.5, 33.9166666666667, 31.3333333333333, 36, 33.0833333333333, 
33.1666666666667, 32.4166666666667, 34.1666666666667, 32.1666666666667, 
32.1666666666667, 37.3333333333333, 36.1666666666667, 33.6666666666667, 
36.4166666666667, 35.4166666666667, 35.5, 36.5833333333333, 33.8333333333333, 
34.4166666666667, 33.5833333333333, 35.6666666666667, 34.75, 
36.1666666666667, 31.1666666666667, 37.5, 31.6666666666667, 33.1666666666667, 
32.0833333333333, 33.5833333333333, 32.1666666666667, 32.4166666666667, 
31.25, 33.5833333333333, 31.5), gene = c(18.265481735128, 17.553682163378, 
17.450005832624, 17.8719936539426, 17.6439644306893, 17.8195797128757, 
17.7327533149751, 17.8626472422709, 18.4375411245124, 17.7206616316039, 
17.8324727651774, 17.6831637379254, 16.3797370363944, 16.2274547911749, 
16.1081681682918, 15.7581300013604, 16.3283156117628, 16.6112399890101, 
16.2097766576023, 16.353875382536, 16.1630593358039, 16.1941586675123, 
16.270535309697, 16.4154082664562, 16.0543656477653, 16.2056037427263, 
16.0414009536146, 15.8233199504989, 15.9644539321719, 16.0035065577481, 
15.1967778769911, 15.5873577174736, 15.4748920755074, 15.8414050703223, 
16.036749175609, 15.6950267375145, 16.2487211678851, 16.4280535060295, 
16.1600327464311, 15.9933079171589, 16.4159279247705, 15.8740001632907, 
16.2547699681823, 15.9199201254046, 15.7748035384056, 16.0895632695324, 
15.9950306563657, 16.1150404336735)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-48L))
```

I want to see if the gene expression `gene` (numeric) is correlated to the 
 continuous variable `VO2max` (numeric) across the two groups of exercised vs non_exercised (`label`) and four strains of mice (`strain`).

This is the model that I am thinking but not sure if I am correct:

```
# fit model
> fit <- lm(gene ~ VO2max + label + strain, data = test)

# output
> tidy(fit)
# A tibble: 6 x 5
  term                 estimate std.error statistic  p.value
  <chr>                   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (Intercept)        18.2        0.686       26.5   7.67e-28
2 VO2max             -0.0000434  0.000101    -0.430 6.69e- 1
3 labelnon_exercised -0.110      0.0767      -1.44  1.57e- 1
4 strainB6 ME        -1.93       0.176      -11.0   6.16e-14
5 strainEC77 ME      -1.70       0.111      -15.3   8.73e-19
6 strainIAI ME       -1.53       0.142      -10.8   1.21e-13
```

I am not sure if this is the correct approach or how to interpret the results. Can someone please assist?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you are asking too much, with so many variables, from simple multiple regression. Expect wrong signs, and other unexplainable results. Supporting comments from [a source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909769?seq=1), to quote:

> The problems involved in obtaining meaningful coefficients of regression by the method of least squares with such intercorrelated data are well known [2, 13, 21]

A potential solution, apply Factor Analysis to construct variables as in this work ['Use of factor scores in multiple regression analysis for estimation of body weight by certain body measurements in Romanov Lambs'](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6679909/) and also a [related work here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/09712119.2007.9706664).

In the context of your problem, follow the work in these two articles carefully. Note, convert your labels into 0/1 dummy variables.

For the advanced students, one can also look into Factor Analysis Regression, which may be appropriate to [quote a source](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909769?seq=1):

> Factor analysis appears to be a particularly appropriate tool in the field of economics where many “independent” variables have high intercorrelation and where there are errors in all the variables .

Also, more pertinent comments relating to coefficients, which differ from more facilely generated Least-Squares Regression parameters:

> Stochastic linear equations can be obtained from factor analysis which give better coefficients (better from the standpoint of their economic meaning and their theoretical expectation) then do regression equations obtained through a traditional least squares [9].

which, in my opinion, based on my personal anguish experienced with stepwise regression routines dropping major logical variables and wrong signs, is valuable (more like priceless) advice.

Comment: but what are the different pvalues in the output that I have shown are telling?